# Sugawara construction in $G$-WZW models

Tags: string-theory, wess-zumino-witten

Lorenz argues that Virasoro generator $L_n$ admits a mode expansion in terms of conserved currents

> $$L_n = \gamma\sum_{\alpha}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}:J^{a}_{n}J^{a}_{m-n}:\space\space\space \gamma = \frac{1}{2(k+h^{\lor})}$$

For every $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, Virasoro generator can be written as a Contour integral over complex unit circle $S^1$

$$L_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{T(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\tag{1}$$

Where $T(z) = \gamma\sum_{\alpha}J^{a}(z)J^{a}(z)$ in Sugawara construction. From the Laurent expansion of $J^{a}(z)J^{a}(z)$,

$$\begin{align}L_n = \frac{\gamma}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{\sum_{\alpha}J^{a}(z)J^{a}(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz &= \frac{\gamma}{2\pi i}\sum_{\alpha}\oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{J^{a}(z)J^{a}(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz \\ &=  \frac{\gamma}{2\pi i}\sum_{\alpha}\oint_{|z| = 1}\frac{\sum_{(k,m)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}:J^{a}_{k}J^{a}_{k-m}:z^k}{z^{n+1}}dz\\ &= \frac{\gamma}{2\pi i}\sum_{\alpha}\sum_{(k,m)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}:J^{a}_{k}J^{a}_{k-m}:\oint_{|z| = 1} z^{k-n-1}dz\end{align}\tag{2}$$

Where Contour integral evaluates to $\displaystyle \oint_{|z| = 1} z^{k-n-1}dz = \begin{cases}2\pi i, \space k = n\\ 0, \space k\neq n\end{cases}$. Thus, one obtains the following mode expansion

$$L_n = \gamma\sum_{\alpha}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}:J^{a}_{n}J^{a}_{n-m}:\space\space\space \gamma = \frac{1}{2(k+h^{\lor})}\tag{3}$$

Does this correctly derive the mode expansion?

Comment: I am not familiar with the Sugawara construction, but to clarify, are your $J^a(z)$ your currents? If so, then I would assume here that all you need to do is to insert the Laurent mode expansion of $J(z)$ with proper weight (as it looks like you did in line 2), but then the contour integral can then just be written as a delta function $\delta_{k+n,0}$ (I am also assuming your modes for $J(z)$ are $J_k^a$ and so on). Otherwise, it looks ok to me.

Comment: @MathZilla Yes, $\{J^{a}(z)\}_{a}$ is collection of our conserved currents that live in the affine Lie algebra $\hat{\mathfrak{g}}$, and $\{J^{a}_{n}(z)\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ are the modes coming from Laurent expansion of $J^{a}(z)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then why is there only a single $z^k$ in the Laurent expansion of the currents since if (roughly) $J(z) \sim \sum_n J^a_n z^{n-h}$ (only the holomorphic side). Why would it not be $J(z)J(z) = \sum_n z^{2(n-h)-m}J_nJ_{n-m}$? Is the weight of the currents zero? (I am just trying to get all the details and poke holes in it to make sure it's right). Also, why is the expansion $z^n$ and not $z^{-n}$?

Comment: @MathZilla I used the fact that $J(z)$ is holomorphic, and so it admits Laurent series: $$J^{a}(z) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} J^a_n z^{n}\tag{1}$$ In which case the product Laurent expansion of $J^{\alpha}(z)J^{\alpha}(z)$ becomes: $$\sum_{(k,m)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}}:J^{a}_{k}J^{a}_{k-m}z^k\tag{2}$$ The sum is over $z^n$ in $(1)$ because I thought that this holds for arbitrary complex holomorphic functions $f(z)$.

Comment: Lastly, I used this reference for coming up with product Laurent series: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359921/multiplying-laurent-series

Comment: I see nothing wrong then with the derivation, good job!

Comment: @MathZilla Thank you very much for your so valuable feedback! If you want, you can include your comments in an answer and I'll happily accept it.